# Как выровнять в строку?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выровнять второй столбик в ряд? Почему-то переносится текст
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Уборка санузлов</td>
        <td>800 ₽ шт.</td>
        <td>Добавить</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Удаление прикипевшей плёнки с оконных рам</td>
        <td>+ 2000 ₽</td>
        <td>Добавить</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px 8px;
}

tr {
    background-color: var(--color-blue);
    color: var(--color-white);
}

td {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 24px;
}

td:first-child {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-top-left-radius: 87px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 87px;

}
td:last-child {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-top-right-radius: 87px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 87px;
}
```

Нужно чтобы было вот так, чтобы строки не переносились.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к стилям нужной колонки свойство `white-space`

```
 td:nth-child(2) {
    white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, мне нужно задать это только второй колонки, да? Ну т.к у первой колонки перенос должен

Comment: @KILLER да, можете применить к тем ячейкам, в которых перенос не нужен